# If the limit of a sequence is 0, does it imply that the sequence is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say that for a positive sequence $u_n$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$. Would this imply that the sequence is decreasing after some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? Intuitively it seems like that has to be the case.

I'm asking because the alternating series test requires both that the sequence is decreasing *and* that the limit is 0. This seems to imply that this intuition isn't correct.

Comment: Is this not a consequence of the ratio test?

Comment: Try $u_n$ such that $u_{2n}=0$ and $u_{2n+1}=1/n$.

Comment: Ouch. Intuition isn't something to go by.

Comment: @Kelenner : This isn't a *positive* sequence, but can be transparently adapted to one...

Comment: If the generating function had no critical points from the starting index, it is necessarily decreasing. However, this is not necessarily true for your given condition.

Comment: @Eric Towers You are true, but it was not indicated "positive" in the original question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any positive strictly decreasing sequence 
$$a_1,a_2,a_3,...$$
with limit zero.

Then the sequence
$$a_2,a_1,a_4,a_3,a_6,a_5,...$$
is a positive sequence with limit zero, but zig-zags up and down forever.

Here's another example which relates to the issue you raised about alternating series . . .

Define a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ by
$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{1}{2^n}}}&\text{if}\;n\;\text{is odd}\\[6pt]
-{\large{\frac{1}{n}}}&\text{if}\;n\;\text{is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
diverges, even though it's an alternating series whose terms approach zero.

Note that the sequence $|a_n|$ is a positive sequence which approaches zero, but has no tail which is always decreasing.

Answer (score 5):

No it does not: Take the sequence -1/n. It increases, and its limit is 0.

Comment: You got me there, but I forgot to mention that I meant a positive sequence